# Set hostname resolution in Windows without admin

Tags: networking, windows-10, hostname

Is it possible to somehow recognize hostnames without DNS record or hosts file edit? Is there some other way? I do not have admin privs for our company's PC so I cannot edit %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and still I need name translation.

Answer (score 0):

By default Windows will be able to resolve addresses of devices residing on the same subnet, He will utilise NetBIOS name resolution. Other than that there is mDNS, again you can count on mDNS if your target device/s reside on the same subnet as Your Workstation, more about mDNS and Windows OS - in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23624525/11490059).

Comment: I simply need to be able to enter hostnames into browser, instead of IP addresses. Usually I'd put them into hosts file but I do not have admin privileges to update it.

Comment: Above mentioned (NetBIOS and mDNS) will work inside browser if your target maschines are on the same subnet as your PC - Other than that, without admin privileges there is not much that You can do. You can ask your IT sys admin to edit the host file for You, or to put your local user acc inside "Network Configuration Operators group", then you could point your PC to your own self hosted DNS server and there You can add those Resource Records. Or You could just make a shortcuts to those IPs so that you don't have to type them every time you need them - You just open that shortcut

Comment: Those are AIX servers, in completely different network and their web apps are hardcoded with IP addresses, which makes them appear like they are Internet servers, which makes local proxy server kick in, effectively shielding me out...Complex scenario, outside of character limit here on SU, that why I just asked, hoping there will be some neat trick like %APPDATA%\hosts per user. Which is nonsense, as i think about that, that would be extremely dangerous. Anyway, thanks for the help.